# Remove a specific pattern in a tab file

Tags: bash

I have a file such as:

```
scaffold_10_1   YP_02917613.1   0.722   397 90  1   55021   53805   70  446 1.803E-180  566
scaffold_282_0  YP_004091438.1  0.799   317 102 1   55023   53395   66  442 2.282E-173  546
scaffold_15     YP_009676312.1  0.021   327 14  1   55320   52895
IDBA_scaffold_66230_1   YP_004091438.1         0.789    317 122 1   55023   53395   66  442 2.282E-173  506
scf7180005161552_2      YP_004091438.1          0.789   317 122 1   55023   53395   66  442 2.282E-173  506
```

And the idea is simply to remove the last number part of all names in the first column and get:

```
scaffold_10 YP_02917613.1   0.722   397 90  1   55021   53805   70  446 1.803E-180  566
scaffold_282    YP_004091438.1  0.799   317 102 1   55023   53395   66  442 2.282E-173  546
scaffold_15     YP_009676312.1  0.021   327 14  1   55320   52895
IDBA_scaffold_66230    YP_004091438.1         0.789 317 122 1   55023   53395   66  442 2.282E-173  506
scf7180005161552     YP_004091438.1            0.789    317 122 1   55023   53395   66  442 2.282E-173  506
```

As you can see, sometime there is no `_number` after the first `_number_` as

```
scaffold_15
```

Have you an idea to deal with that?

Thank you for you help.

For brunorey:
Here is tha table I got:

```
scaffold_10   YP_02917613.1   0.722   397 90  1   55021   53805   70  446 1.803E-180  566
scaffold_282  YP_004091438.1  0.799   317 102 1   55023   53395   66  442 2.282E-173  546
scaffold     YP_009676312.1  0.021   327 14  1   55320   52895
IDBAscaffold_66230_1   YP_004091438.1         0.789    317 122 1   55023   53395   66  442 2.282E-173  506
scf7180005161552      YP_004091438.1          0.789   317 122 1   55023   53395   66  442 2.282E-173  506
```

as you can see, the 15 of the `scaffold_15` has been removed but I want to keep it.

Comment: Do you want to do it for every line or just the first one of each file?

Comment: For every line in the file

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
cat file.csv | sed -e 's/\([A-Ba-b0-9_]*\)\(_[0-9]*\)\(.*\)/\1\3/' > file-without-number.csv
```

How does this work?

- `sed` is the inline editor,
- Running sed with command `s/` will search and replace. Syntax is slash sparated: `s/search_patter/replace_pattern`.
- Search pattern is `\([A-Ba-b0-9_]*\)\(_[0-9]*\)\(.*\)`. It will split the line into 3 parts:

  - 1) `\([A-Ba-b0-9_]*\)` any string composed by letters, numbers or _
  - 2) ...followed by `_number` (matching `\(_[0-9]*\)`)
  - 3) The rest of the line (matching `\(.*\)`)
- `\1\3` Will replace the string with only parts 1 and 3, thus removing 2

Comment: It works for all kind of scaffold names but not for the scf7180005161552_2 one.

Comment: Oh and there is still the IDBAscaffold_66230_1  that should be IDBAscaffold_66230 and the scaffold_15 should not be changed in scaffold

Comment: Do try my new version.

Comment: I put the output in my first post to explain you what is going wrong.

Comment: It still removes the `scaffold_15` part and does not remove the `IDBAscaffold_66230_1` part ...

Answer (score 1):

You can try with this sed :

```
sed 's/\(^[^_]*_[^_]*\)\(_[0-9]\{1,\}\)\([[:blank:]]\{1,\}.*\)/\1\3/' infile
```

With data like IDBA_scaffold_66230_1, you can try this awk :

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"}$1~/.*_[0-9]+_[0-9]+$/{sub(/_[0-9]+$/,"",$1)}1' infile
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but it does not work for `IDBA_scaffold_66230_1` and `scf7180005161552_2` for instance..

Comment: I get scf7180005161552_2 with scf7180005161552_2. What do you want to get ? Like you change your data with  IDBA_scaffold_66230_1, It's more difficult with sed. You can try with awk in my updated answer.